# Loading JSON file gives serialization error

Tags: c#, json

I have below JSON file,

```
[
  {
    "applicationConfig": {
      "Name": "Name1",
      "Site": "Site1"
    },
    "pathConfig": {
      "SourcePath": "C:\\Temp\\Outgoing1",
      "TargetPath": "C:\\Files"
    },
    "credentialConfig": {
      "Username": "test1",
      "password": "super1"
    }
  },
  {
    "applicationConfig": {
      "Name": "Name2",
      "Site": "Site2"
    },
    "pathConfig": {
      "SourcePath": "C:\\Temp\\Outgoing2",
      "TargetPath": "C:\\Files"
    },
    "credentialConfig": {
      "Username": "test2",
      "password": "super2"
    }
  }
]
```

And below are C# classes structure,

```
public class Configurations
{
    public List<ApplicationConfig> ApplicationConfigs { get; set; }
    public List<PathConfig> PathConfigs { get; set; }
    public List<CredentialConfig> CredentialConfigs { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationConfig
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
}

public class PathConfig
{
    public string SourcePath { get; set; }
    public string TargetPath { get; set; }
}

public class CredentialConfig
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Now trying to load JSON and getting below error,

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"./Config.json"))
        {
           var X = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configurations>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

> $exception    {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   into type 'ConsoleApp8.Configurations' because the type requires a
>   JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON
>   object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position
>   1."}  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

What else I need to serialize?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JSON represents an array - although the closing `[` should be a `]`. But you're trying to serialize it into a single `Configurations` object. Additionally, you seem to be expecting separate arrays for the application configs, path configs and credential configs - whereas your JSON shows an array of objects, each of which has all three.

I suspect you want:

```
public class Configuration
{
    [JsonProperty("applicationConfig")]
    ApplicationConfig ApplicationConfig { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pathConfig")]
    PathConfig PathConfig { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("credentialConfig")]
    CredentialConfig CredentialConfig { get; set; }
}

// Other classes as before, although preferably with the password property more conventionally named
```

Then use:

```
List<Configuration> configurations = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Configuration>>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

You'll then have a list of configuration objects, each of which will have the three "subconfiguration" parts.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON class definition is close but not quite. Moroever the last `[` must be `]`

JSON class definition is created wtih [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
 public partial class Configuration
{
    [JsonProperty("applicationConfig")]
    public ApplicationConfig ApplicationConfig { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pathConfig")]
    public PathConfig PathConfig { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("credentialConfig")]
    public CredentialConfig CredentialConfig { get; set; }
}

public partial class ApplicationConfig
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Site")]
    public string Site { get; set; }
}

public partial class CredentialConfig
{
    [JsonProperty("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public partial class PathConfig
{
    [JsonProperty("SourcePath")]
    public string SourcePath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TargetPath")]
    public string TargetPath { get; set; }
}
```

Finally you need to serialize with

```
var config_list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Configuration>>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a typo, you are opening the square bracket instead of closing it in the JSON file.

> [   {
>       "applicationConfig": {
>         "Name": "Name1",
>         "Site": "Site1"
>       },
>       "pathConfig": {
>         "SourcePath": "C:\Temp\Outgoing1",
>         "TargetPath": "C:\Files"
>       },
>       "credentialConfig": {
>         "Username": "test1",
>         "password": "super1"
>       }   },   {
>       "applicationConfig": {
>         "Name": "Name2",
>         "Site": "Site2"
>       },
>       "pathConfig": {
>         "SourcePath": "C:\Temp\Outgoing2",
>         "TargetPath": "C:\Files"
>       },
>       "credentialConfig": {
>         "Username": "test2",
>         "password": "super2"
>       }   } **[** ***<-HERE***